# ccDraw. Fill screen everywhere except on sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

So I am trying to get a very basic "flashlight"-style thing going in one of my games.

The way I was getting it to work, was having a layer on top of my game screen, and this layer would draw a black rectangle with ~ 80% opacity, creating the look of darkness on top of my game scene.

```
ccDrawSolidRect(ccp(0,0), ccp(480,320), ccc4f(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
```

What I want to do is draw this rectangle EVERYWHERE on the screen, except for around a cone of vision that will represent the "light source".

What this would create would be a dark overlay on top of everything except for the light, giving it the illusion of a torch/light/flashlight.

The only way I can foresee this happening is by using `ccDrawSolidPoly()`, but since the position of the light source changes, so would the vertices for the poly.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be great.

Comment: Could you upload an image describing what you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ccDrawSolidPoly()` and avoid having to manually update vertices. For this you can create a new subclass of `CCNode` representing your light object, and do your custom shape drawing in its `-(void)draw` method.

The `ccDraw...()` functions will draw relative to the local sprite coordinates, so you can then move and rotate your new sprite to suit your needs and *cocos2d* will do the vertices transformations for you.

---

*Update*: I found out that you might be better off subclassing `CCDrawNode` instead of `CCNode`, as it has some facilities for raw OpenGL drawing (OpenGL's vertexArrayBuffer and vertexBufferObject internal variables and a buffer for vertices, their colors and their texCoords). If your stuff is very simple, maybe subclassing the plain `CCNode` is enough.

Comment: This ^. Good answer, was what I was after

Answer (score 0):

Could a png be used instead as a mask, as the layer above
Like that binocular vision you sometimes see in cartoons?
Or a filter similar to a photoshop mask that darkens as it grows outwardly to wards the edge of the screen

Just a thought anyway...

A picture of more of what your trying to explain might be good too